# Streaming a YouTube playlist on Raspberry Pi and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl, mplayer

I'm working on a Voice Assistant based on the Raspberry Pi (2 B+), and one of the functions I was looking to integrate was to play my playlist whenever I want it to.

I tried out using youtube-dl and mplayer within os.system like so, inspired by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160221) answer

`youtube-dl --playlist-random -o - "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFepKcct_CJG0mu-nb-HvQ52FRKTEO6hT" | mplayer -`

I understand that `youtube-dl` will download the video and send the stream piped to `mplayer` which will play the music.
What is happening is that the code is playing the first video flawlessly, but as soon as the video ends, `mplayer` just stops at whatever was the last frame. It's not continuing to the next video even though I can see `youtube-dl` is to downloading videos in the playlist.

Is there any way I can play multiple songs in a playlist using `youtube-dl` seamlessly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `omxplayer` instead...
try this small sh script with named pipe
first `mkfifo /home/midia/omxfifo`
then save this script below `script.sh` and `chmod +x`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
FileToPlay="$1"
for LINK in $(cat $FileToPlay)
do
    echo "Playing : $LINK"

    omxplayer -o hdmi --vol -2 $(youtube-dl -g -f mp4 $LINK)</home/midia/omxfifo>/dev/null 2>&1 & echo -n '' >/home/midia/omxfifo


    echo "$LINK" >> watched.log
done
```

call the script like this:

```sh
./script.sh file_with_yt_url.txt
```